# Selecting several users on Facebook, non-manually?

Tags: facebook, firebug

Is it possible to (perhaps with Firebug) or some other method to select ALL your contacts in ONE GO when creating an event on Facebook? How?

Comment: I'm confused, is this a programming question?

Comment: I wasnt sure if this should go under Superuser or here. I ended up putting it here, because I figured the solution would involve firebug, and therefore code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the script below:

javascript:elms=document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByTagName('li');for(var fid in elms){if(typeof elms[fid] === 'object'){fs.click(elms[fid]);}}

Go to your event page click to invite people then paste this code in the URL bar and hit enter.